# 'help' function not showing info about imported functions

Tags: python

Suppose I have 2 files: main.py and test.py. The contents of test.py are

```
def say(name):
     return name
```

The main.py contains a single line `from test import *`

My question is the following: when I import main.py from REPL and run `help(main)`, I want to see 'say' function as an output, but that doesn't happen. Is there any way I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dir(main)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to list all the names in a module including those imported from other modules.

Notice, only members owned by the module are shown in `help()`. Nevertheless, you can force your module to take ownership of imported names by explicitely indexing your module with the magic module property [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Make the contents of main.py to be:

```
from test import *
__all__ = ['say']
```